# Why are geodesics preserved by the quotient with the isometry group $M/G$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to prove that if $\langle M,g\rangle$ is a riemannian manifold and $G = Isom(M)$ acts properly discontinuous on $M$, then a geodesic $c$ is send to another geodesic by the map $\pi: M \twoheadrightarrow M/G$ (canonical projection), where the metric in $M/G$ is given by $h = \pi_{*}g$. I'm trying to prove the result using only the affine connection, however I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you know about the projection map when the action is properly discontinuous?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis it's a local diffeomorphism, actually, an isometry.

Comment: @user40276 Use the fact that being a geodesic is a local property, namely that the covariant derivative, along the curve, of its tangent vector vanishes. Since you have a local isometry, local properties will be preserved.